# jQuery Address find out which element was clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-address

I using jquery.address() to load my pages through ajax:

$.address.state('').init(function() {

```
// Initializes the plugin
$('#menu a').address();
$('#nextprev a').address();

}).change(function(event) {

// Loads the page content and inserts it into the content area
$.ajax({
    url: $.address.state() + event.path,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      $('title').html($('title', data).html());
      $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
      $('#content').html($('#content', data).html());
      loadstuff();
      startAnimation();
    }
});

var startAnimation = function(data) {
... some animation going on here
});
```

Currently after the code calls ajax to load the next page, the next page flies in through startAnimation(). That works really fine so far.

However I have a #next and a #prev element within #nextprev. I want address to find out which of them was clicked, and then load a different function (i.e. startAnimation2()).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define in a markup attribute (or in a hidden input / local pc memory) the current animation index, someting like :

```
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="current-animation" />
```

and then get the value :

```
$('input[name="current-animation"]').val();
```

Alternative with markup :

```
<div id="animation-data" data-current="3" data-animation="animation-1"></div>
```

Comment: Cool yes something like that. I also already thought about cookies, but i would like to have 2 different animation types for #next and #prev. How do I find out which was actually clicked? The markup would only provide one animation type....

Comment: Post edited. You can do it as it's showed or using multiple input elements.